# Modulo Arithmetic in Modified Geometric Progression

Tags: algorithm, math, modulo, algebra

We know that sum of n terms in a Geometric Progression is given by
Sn = a1(1-r^n)/(1-r) if the series is of the form a1, a1*r, a1*r^2, a1*r^3....a1*r^n.

Now i have modified geometric progression where series is of the form
a1, (a1*r) mod p , (a1*r^2) mod p, (a1*r^3) mod p.....(a1*r^n)mod p where a1 is the initial term, p is prime number and r is common ratio. Nth term of this series is given by: (a1 * r^n-1) mod p.

I am trying to get summation formula for above modified GP and struggling very hard. If anyone can throw some light on it or advice on finding efficient algorithm for finding sum without iterating for all the n terms, will be of great help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has no relation to programming, just mathematics

Comment: One can find efficient algorithm for the above question. That is what I have asked.

Comment: In principle the solution is the same, x is the solution of `a1*(r^N-1) = (r-1)*x mod p`. The problem is that `p` and `r-1` may have common divisors, which requires careful handling in the interpretation of the extended Euclidean algorithm, `XGCD(p,r-1)`.

Comment: @LutzL. Thanks for the reply. Can you explain with a very simple example.?

Comment: You have to find `n` or what?

Comment: @Alfran Yes....

Comment: I provided an answer, see the `Discrete Logarithm` and `Baby-Step Giant-Step algorithm`, if you can't understand tell me, I will provide you the implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that if `r` is a [primitive root modulo `p`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n).
Then we can reduce complexity of the sum.

We have to find `S = a1*1 + a1*r + a1*r^2 + ... + a1*r^n`. Then we write `S` in the closed form as `S = a1*(r^n - 1) / (r - 1)`.

Now it can be reduced to:

```
 a1*(r^n - 1) / (r - 1) = S (mod p)
=> a1*r^n = S * (r - 1) + 1 (mod p)
```

Now take discrete logarithm with base r both sides,

```
   log(a1*r^n) = log_r(S*(r-1) + 1 (mod p))
   =>log_r(a1) + n*log_r(r) = log_r(S*(r-1) + 1 (mod p))
   =>n*log_r(r) = log_r(S*(r-1) + 1 (mod p)) - log_r(a1) (mod(p-1))
   =>n*1 = log_r(S*(r-1) + 1 (mod (p-1))) - log_r(a1) (mod (p-1))
```

Note that if `a1` is `1` then the last term is `0`.

Let S = 6, r = 3, and m = 7, a1 = 1.
Then, we want to solve for n in the following congruence:

```
     (3^n - 1)/(3 - 1) = 6 (mod 7)
=> 3^n - 1 = (3 - 1) * 6 (mod 7)
=> 3^n = 2 * 6 + 1 (mod 7)
=> 3^n = 6 (mod 7)
```

Then we take the [discrete logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) of both sides:

```
     log_3(3^n) = log_3(6) (mod (7-1))
=> n * log_3(3) = log_3(6) (mod 6)
=> n * 1 = 3 (mod 6)
=> n = 3 (mod 6)
```

So, n = 3.

You can use [Baby-step Giant-step](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby-step_giant-step) algorithm to solve this in `O(sqrt(m))`.
If you want implementation in code I will provide you.

Comment: For implementation we need to find modulo inverse right

Comment: Hi, I am trying to implement baby step algorithm from this link.. 
 http://www.infoarena.ro/blog/meet-in-the-middle. There formula reduces to p^ i[sqrt(n)] = q*p^-j (mod n). So I have to calculate p^-j, is it have to be done by extended euclidian algorithm?. Is there any code sample for the same. Found few links but they are not very clear.

Comment: You can learn this algorithm from https://math.berkeley.edu/~sagrawal/su14_math55/notes_shank.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The principal relation is the same, the sum `x` is the solution of

```
a1*(r^N-1) = (r-1)*x mod p.
```

The difficulty to observe is that `p` and `r-1` may have common divisors, which is not really a problem as `r-1` divides into `r^N-1`, but still requires careful handling.

Modular division can be achieved via multiplication with the inverse and that can be computed via the extended Euclidean algorithm. Any implementation of

```
 d,u,v = XGCD(r-1,p)
```

returns the largest common divisor `d` and Bezout factors `u,v` so that

```
u*(r-1)+v*p = d
```

Multiplication with `f/d`, `f = a1*(r^N-1)` results in

```
(u*f/d)*(r-1) + (v*f/d)*p = f = a1*(r^N-1)
```

so that the solution can be identified as `x = u*(f/d)`. An implementation will thus follow the lines of

```
 rN = powmod(r,N,p)
 f = a1*(rN-1) mod p

 d,u,v = XGCD(r-1,p)

 return u*(f/d) mod p
```

Comment: The above implementation will calculate sum of n numbers in progression, what I need is a summation formula for n numbers in series just like Sn = a1(1-r^n)/(1-r) for normal geometric progression.

Comment: What exactly is the difference? And what do you think are typical values for `p` and `r` in your use-case?

Comment: If "p is a prime" (from the OP), `r-1` and `p` are relatively prime unless `r-1` is a multiple of `p`, which is the same as `r=1`.

Comment: Yes, that is true. Then the inverse of `r-1` can also be computed via the little theorem of Fermat as `powmod(r-1,p-2,p)`.