# How to find n in ((r^n-1)/(r-1))%p = s, if p is prime?

Tags: math, primes

I thought of reducing it to this, but couldn't come up to any conclusion.
((r^n-1)/(r-1))%p == ((r^n-1)*(invmod(r-1,p)))%p.

it's also given that n should lie in between [1,p) if possible and for every r^i where i belongs [1,p) are distinct and contains all the numbers from [1,p).

Please help !

Comment: Is it (r^n) - 1 or r^(n-1)?

Comment: Sounds like it reduces to the [discrete logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) problem, for which there is no efficient solution. You need to give more context: Is this a maths problem for which you want a general solution? Do you need to solve this by hand for some given values of *r*, *p* and *s*? Do you need to write a program that solves this? How big can *p* get?

Comment: @tom without further specification this seems to be a general problem. The best we can do is to refine the formula to a form which is easy to digest for a method of analization, that is, make sure that only n is on the left side and the right side is as understandable and computable as possible.

Comment: Online contest or the same teacher? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44613643/modulo-arithmetic-in-modified-geometric-progression

Comment: There have been a lot of discrete log questions on SO in the last couple days

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modulo Arithmetic in Modified Geometric Progression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44613643/modulo-arithmetic-in-modified-geometric-progression)

Comment: @MBo: Same teacher is my guess.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume in this answer that we are talking about r^(n-1)

x % p = s

means that exists an arbitrary integer number m so that

x = p * m + s

since the % is periodic and divides numbers into modulo classes. This means that

(r ^ (n - 1)) / (r - 1) = p * m + s

where m is an arbitrary integer number. This means that

r ^ (n - 1) = (p * m + s) * (r - 1)

Since all the numbers are positive, we can turn this into logarithmic formula:

ln (r ^ (n - 1)) = ln ((p * m + s) * (r - 1))

Since power inside a logarithm is equivalent to a scalar, we can do some further modifications:

(n - 1) * ln(r) = ln ((p * m + s) * (r - 1))

so

n * ln(r) = ln ((p * m + s) * (r - 1)) + ln(r)

therefore

n * ln(r) = ln((p * m + s) * r * (r - 1))

Finally:

n = ln((p * m + s) * r * (r - 1)) / ln(r)

We can further refine this if needed:

n = log(r, (p * m + s) * r * (r - 1))

So

n = log(r, r) + log(r, (p * m + s) * (r - 1))

which is

n = 1 + log(r, (p * m + s) * (r - 1))

You will need to analyze the problem space, knowing that n, r and s are in the interval of [1, p) and m is an arbitrary integer. So, the question is: what is the set of possible integer values for m that will allow all the three values to be in the desired interval and what will the possible values be. This is a longer analysis which is outside the scope of a short SO answer, but I think you should be ok from here. If not, then ask another question where you will be stuck and let me know about it.